# flutter get json array

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

Hi I have this JSON as a string as a response for an API call

```
{
    "friends": {
        "data": [],
        "summary": {
            "total_count": 42
        }
    },
    "id": "111111111111111"
}
```

I want to get *friends.data* and *friends.summary.total_count*.
Something like :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < friends.summary.total_count ; i++)
{
    myAmazingArray.pushback(friends.data[i]);
}
```

I think that total_count is the number of contents in the array.
I also know that in order to get the "id" I have to do : `json['name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jsonDecode from dart:convert. Actually you don't even need to use the total_count value at all, if the length in data is the same. You can simply use:

```
 import 'dart:convert';

 final Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = jsonDecode(json);
 final List<dynamic> friendsData = dataMap['friends']['data'];

 for(dynamic friend in friendsData) myAmazingArray.pushback(friend);
```

I don't know what kind of content is contained in `data`, so I suggest you to find out the runtime type (e.g. String, Map etc.) and exchange the word 'dynamic' in my code above to improve the code quality.

If you wanted to do it with total_count:

```
final int total_count = dataMap['friends']['summary']['total_count'];

for(int i=0; i<total_count; i++)
    myAmazingArray.pushback(friendsData[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks man, now I know how to use the different depths with JSON:D